# Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group

Tags: regex

I'm attempting something which I feel should be fairly obvious to me but it's not.  I'm trying to match a string which does NOT contain a specific sequence of characters.  I've tried using `[^ab]`, `[^(ab)]`, etc. to match strings containing no 'a's or 'b's, or only 'a's or only 'b's or 'ba' but not match on 'ab'.  The examples I gave won't match 'ab' it's true but they also won't match 'a' alone and I need them to.  Is there some simple way to do this?

Comment: @finnw maybe he was refering to it into the context of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36754105/3186555?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Use negative lookahead (cf. [Regexr.com explanation](https://regexr.com/7ji4p)):

```
^(?!.*ab).*$
```

UPDATE: In the comments below, I stated that this approach is slower than the one given in [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/20938).  I've run some tests since then, and found that it's really slightly faster.  However, the reason to prefer this technique over the other is not speed, but simplicity.

The other technique, described [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) as a *tempered greedy token*, is suitable for more complex problems, like matching delimited text where the delimiters consist of multiple characters (like HTML, as Luke commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group/977290#comment22132485_977290)).  For the problem described in the question, it's overkill.

For anyone who's interested, I tested with a large chunk of Lorem Ipsum text, counting the number of lines that don't contain the word "quo".  These are the regexes I used:

```
(?m)^(?!.*\bquo\b).+$

(?m)^(?:(?!\bquo\b).)+$
```

Whether I search for matches in the whole text, or break it up into lines and match them individually, the anchored lookahead consistently outperforms the floating one.

Comment: I believe this is more efficient: (?:(?!ab).)*

Comment: Also wants to use start/end markers to enforce the check on the whole string.

Comment: @Blixit: yes, it is. But it's also harder to read, especially for regex newbies. The one I posted will be efficient enough for most applications.

Comment: @Peter: I was fixing that as you posted the comment. Anchors aren't necessary in all cases (eg, when using Java's matches() method), but they don't hurt anything either.

Comment: Don't write code aimed at newbies! If code is hard to read, leave comments/documentation so they can learn, instead of using lesser code that keeps them ignorant.

Comment: If I had thought there would be a noticeable difference between the two approaches, I wouldn't have hesitated to recommend the faster one. On the other hand, regexes are so opaque (if not cryptic), I think it's worthwhile to break the knowledge into smaller, more manageable chunks whenever possible.

Comment: In my case the second one worked, and the first one didn't. I was trying to match certain `<td> .. </td>` elements that contained `windows` somewhere between the start and end tags and not match the TD elements that didn't. I used `<td(?:(?!</td>).)+</td>` to find the whole TD element where `<td(?!.*</td>).*</td>` wouldn't work. Final regex was `<td(?:(?!</td>).)+windows.*?</td>` . For a good example of "breaking the knowledge into smaller chunks" see below where the explanation of the regex characters used is included in the answer.

Comment: @Luke: That is a very different problem.  You're searching for a substring that starts with `AAA` and ends with `BBB`, that does not contain any other instances of `AAA` or `BBB`, but does contain `CCC` (where `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` are arbitrary multi-character sequences).  *This* question is about matching a whole string that does not contain `AAA`.  Peter's approach works here too, but this approach is just as valid, and a little more intuitive.

Comment: If you break my problem down, before worrying about the `windows` part, i first needed to find one complete `<td>...</td>` tag, which involved, as you say, finding the middle section "that does not contain any instances of `aaa` or `bbb`" (this part pretty closely matches the question). I was just adding my experience to try to help anyone else who arrives at this page.

Comment: You just saved my life. I have been banging my head against a wall for an hour trying to match simple out-of-place Javascript inline comments (`<code> // <comment>`) except I wanted to ignore matches where the comment was at the start of the line; I _only_ wanted to move the comment up to its own line. Thanks to you I got it complete in short order.

Comment: if you are planning to not have any "ab" s at all, `(?:(?:(?!.*ab).*).)*` is going to be best

Comment: why is first `.*` needed in `^(?!.*ab).*$` ? In my use case it seems to work without it as well (I use it as `(?!\d+).+` )

Comment: A faster implementation would remove the negative lookahead: `^(?:[^a]*a[^b])*[^a]*$`. Lookahead is expensive. Note this is hard to generalize. Read as "match not 'a' until an 'a' is seen, then match not 'b'; do logic repeatedly then finally match any string of not 'a' until the end"

Comment: In Rust look-aheads are not supported, is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use a look-ahead in a middle part within your regex, to exclude a character group in a sub section of the string to match. This isn't evident from all the answers.

Answer (score 456):

Using a character class such as `[^ab]` will match a **single character** that is not within the set of characters. (With the `^` being the negating part).

To match a string which does not contain the multi-character sequence `ab`, you want to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?:(?!ab).)+$
```

And the above expression disected in regex comment mode is:

```
(?x)    # enable regex comment mode
^       # match start of line/string
(?:     # begin non-capturing group
  (?!   # begin negative lookahead
    ab  # literal text sequence ab
  )     # end negative lookahead
  .     # any single character
)       # end non-capturing group
+       # repeat previous match one or more times
$       # match end of line/string
```

Comment: Dissecting the regex was very helpful for me.  Thank you.

Comment: ..and for replacing it, probably just `^((?!ab).+)$`.

Comment: A small note. The ```.``` from the "any single character" is only for the same line. If you need to do this to multi-line regex, you may need to replace it to ```(.|\n)```

Comment: Thanks for that - very informative. Having played with it, I think it's worth noting that the 'ab' that you've described as, and in your example is, a "literal text sequence" can in fact be a complex regular expression. So if you have a regex that matches some pattern in strings, then wrap that regex inside  '^(?:(?!' and  ').)+$', the resulting regex will match strings that **do not** contain a match for the original regex.

Comment: The Debug feature of [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/) does a great job of illustrating how the negative lookahead works.

Comment: this fails, if the string contains whitespace, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/e312d1494960).

Answer (score 73):

Yes its called negative lookahead. It goes like this - `(?!regex here)`. So `abc(?!def)` will match abc **not** followed by def. So it'll match abce, abc, abck, etc.

Similarly there is positive lookahead - `(?=regex here)`. So `abc(?=def)` will match abc followed by def.

There are also negative and positive lookbehind - `(?<!regex here)` and `(?<=regex here)` respectively

One point to note is that the negative lookahead is zero-width. That is, it does not count as having taken any space.

So it may look like `a(?=b)c` will match "abc" but it won't. It will match 'a', then the positive lookahead with 'b' but it won't move forward into the string. Then it will try to match the 'c' with 'b' which won't work. Similarly `^a(?=b)b$` will match 'ab' and not 'abb' because the lookarounds are zero-width (in most regex implementations).

More information on [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) page

Comment: Referencing the 'lookbehind' operators as well was useful, not all online regex parsers/documentation will include it, even if it is valid and works.

Comment: in regex101.com, `?!` did ignore that group, but it kept matching the rest of the string. Is there a way to use that for making the whole line excluded if it has a specific pattern?

Answer (score 6):

> abc(?!def) will match abc not followed
>   by def. So it'll match abce, abc,
>   abck, etc. what if I want neither def
>   nor xyz will it be abc(?!(def)(xyz))
>   ???

I had the same question and found a solution:

```
abc(?:(?!def))(?:(?!xyz))
```

These non-counting groups are combined by "AND", so it this should do the trick. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where is that quote from? Only part of it comes from [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977316/12695027). Apart from that, you've not answered the Question, but seems to have answered something that you haven't linked to. I think `abc(?:(?!def)(?!xyz))` would do. They're in the con-capturing group already. No need to put another one inside it. They're also not "combined by "AND"". They're checked one at a time, just like `ab` is first checked for `a`, then for `b`, but lookaheads just don't move the cursor along.

Answer (score 5):

Using a regex as you described is the simple way (as far as I am aware). If you want a range you could use [^a-f].

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to pull the negation out of the regular expression entirely:

```
if (!userName.matches("^([Ss]ys)?admin$")) { ... }
```

Comment: While this is useful if you are consuming *just* that expression, as part of a larger expression the negative lookahead method described by Peter allows both positive and negative conditions in a single string.

Comment: Absolutely true. But the question was to "match a string which does NOT contain a specific sequence of characters". I think for that purpose negative lookahead is overkill.

Comment: Can't do this if you're using a text editor.

Comment: Not useful if you're using regex outside of a programming language, like Apache or Nginx config....

Answer (score 3):

Just search for "ab" in the string then negate the result:

```
!/ab/.test("bamboo"); // true
!/ab/.test("baobab"); // false
```

It seems easier and should be faster too.

Answer (score 2):

The regex [^ab] will match for example 'ab ab ab ab' but not 'ab', because it will match on the string ' a' or 'b '.

What language/scenario do you have? Can you subtract results from the original set, and just match ab?

If you are using GNU grep, and are parsing input, use the '-v' flag to invert your results, returning all non-matches. Other regex tools also have a 'return nonmatch' function, too.

If I understand correctly, you want everything except for those items which contain 'ab' anywhere.

Comment: "The regex [^ab] will match for example 'ab ab ab ab' but not 'ab', because it will match on the string ' a' or 'b '.". This seems to be incorrect. `[^ab]` is a character class that matches everything except a's and b's. Obviously it will match the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I might just simply avoid regular expressions altogether and go with something like:

```
if (StringToTest.IndexOf("ab") < 0)
  //do stuff
```

This is likely also going to be much faster (a quick test vs regexes above showed this method to take about 25% of the time of the regex method).  In general, if I know the exact string I'm looking for, I've found regexes are overkill.  Since you know you don't want "ab", it's a simple matter to test if the string contains that string, without using regex.

Comment: This is a good point! If the sequence is a simple string then a regex is over-complicating things; a contains/indexOf check is the more sensible option.