# String negation using regular expressions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negation

Is it possible to do string negation in regular expressions?  I need to match all strings that do not contain the string `".."`.  I know you can use `^[^\.]*$` to match all strings that do not contain `"."` but I need to match more than one character.  I know I could simply match a string containing `".."` and then negate the return value of the match to achieve the same result but I just wondered if it was possible.

Comment: Linked: [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!.*\.\.).*$
```

That causes the expression to not match if it can find a sequence of two periods anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 5):

```
^(?:(?!\.\.).)*$
```

will only match if there are no two consecutive dots anywhere in the string.