# Regex to match phrases not starting with

Tags: regex

This should be an easy one for the regex masters out there.

I need to match all phrases NOT:  
"The smoking areas are located" OR  
 
"The smoking areas are located "

Input:

The smoking areas are located  
Blah blah blah  
The smoking areas are in the basement  
The smoking areas are located in the back of the building  
  
Matches:  
Blah blah blah  
The smoking areas are in the basement  
The smoking areas are located in the back of the building

Comment: I've gotten this far:^(!(?=.*?\The\b)(?=.*?\bsmoking\b)(?=.*?\bareas\b)(?=.*?\bare\b)(?=.*?\blocated\b)).*$

Comment: possible duplicate of [String negation using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153856/string-negation-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
^(?!(The smoking areas are located\s?$)).+$
```

It basically matches anything, given that "The smoking areas are located" doesn't occur. (Negative look ahead)

Thanks to Joseph for pointing out I had missed one of the cases.

Comment: That won't match the last line. You should add a `$` to the end of the lookahead: http://regexr.com?3098k

Comment: You're absolutely right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the equivalent of `not mystring.startswith('xyz')` in your language of choice? A regex is pretty heavyweight for this kind of operation.