# PHP Regex - negate a match if it contains a word (string)

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I've tried many ways to do this, the only one which seems to partially do what I want is the lookahead negation described in [String negation using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153856/string-negation-using-regular-expressions) and [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex) but I can't get it to work with my current regex.

Assuming I have this string:

```
[url=http://www.example.com]this url BB tag should match[/url]
[url=http://www.example.com][spoiler]this url BB tag shouldn't match[/spoiler][/url]
```

Edit: More in-depth string which shouldn't return a match for debugging:

```
[url=http://www.example.com]Lorem[spoiler]this url BB tag shouldn't match[/spoiler]Ipsum[/url]
```

And the current regex pattern:

```
#\[url=([\w]+?://.*?)\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is
```

Edit: I'm using the following regex (without # and #is) to debug it on Regex Buddy:

```
\[url=([\w]+?://.*?)\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]
```

(these 2 regex should have the same effect on my application as I can easily adapt it, so work with the latter if it makes more sense)

Will match both lines in the string. I want it to don't return a match when there's a `[spoiler]` string between the `[url=xxxx://yyyy]` and `[/url]`.

I think it can be done with the negative lookahead but I can't seem to find a way to insert it in the current regex without turning it unusable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

```
'#\[url=([^\]]+)\](?!\[spoiler\])(.*?)\[/url\]#'
```

Comment: It's still returning a match for `[url=http://www.google.com][spoiler][/spoiler][/url]` on my php and regex testers.

Comment: Here's my test `preg_match('#\[url=([^\]]+)\](?!\[spoiler\])(.*?)\[/url\]#', '[url=http://www.google.com][spoiler][/spoiler][/url]', $m); print_r($m);` It returns nothing tho (which is what you want).

Comment: Oh sorry, for my comment above it actually doesn't return a match for your regex, however, if I add any character before the `[spoiler]` it'll return a match: `[url=http://wwww.google.com]Hi[spoiler][/spoiler][/url]`

Comment: Adding a .* inside the lookahead seems to do the trick, I'll debug it and post results.

Comment: Alright, `(?!.*\[spoiler\])` lookahead does the trick, but I still wanted to keep the \w iteration and :// check for this pattern, so here's the final regex: `#\[url=(?=[^_\W]+?://)([^\]]+)\](?!.*\[spoiler\])(.*?)\[/url\]#i`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh I found an exception, `[url=xxxx://yyyy]zzzz[/url][spoiler][/spoiler]` wouldn't return any match with the regex above, here is the fixed version if anyone ever gets into a similar problem while editing a phpbb2 pattern: `#\[url=(?=[^_\W]+?://)([^\]]+)\](?!.*?\[spoiler\].*?\[/url\])(.*?)\[/url\]#i`