# Regexp if contains XXX but not contains XXX

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Trying to archive a regexp to filter bounced emails differing them from SPAM or temporary undeliverable.

Our idea is to grab certain words the expression could contain (code + word) but ignore the whole line if it contans others such as (SPAM|temporarily undeliverable|disk quota exceeded) etc, as this would not be considered permanent bounces. We've managed the first part and found a couple of answers here about negative regexp (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153856/string-negation-using-regular-expressions) but been completely unsuccessful in mixing both in one group sentence so far.

Something like:

```
.*(5.3.0|5.1.0).*(User unknown|invalid|Unknown address|doesn't have a)
```

but not match if anywhere else on the same line contains xxx words. Something like:

```
^(?!(SPAM|temporarily undeliverable|disk quota exceeded)).*$
```

So the following first line would match but the second should not

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.3.0 - Other mail system problem 554-"delivery
>   error: dd This user doesn't have a btinternet.com account
>   (xxxxxxxx@xxxxxinternet.com) [0] - mta1000.bt.mail.ird.yahoo.com"
>   (delivery attempts: 0)
>
> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 550-'RCPT
>   TO: Mailbox disk quota exceeded' (delivery
>   attempts: 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching only at the start of the string for your negation. You just need to add a `.*`

try

```
^(?!.*(SPAM|temporarily undeliverable|disk quota exceeded)).*(5.3.0|5.1.0).*(User unknown|invalid|Unknown address|doesn't have a)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31ro4)

Comment: Simple ;) Thanks. Done some additional improvements and real lines for testing and seems to work great: http://regexr.com?31rp2