# Getting paramValue for paramName in specifed querystring using regex

Tags: java, regex

I like to write a java utility method that returns paramValue for paramName in specified query string

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\&?(\\w+)\\=  (I don't know what to put here) ");

public String getParamValue(String entireQueryString, String paramName)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(entireQueryString);
    while(m.find()) {
        if(m.group(1).equals(paramName)) {
            return m.group(2);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I will be invoking this method from my servlet,

```
    String qs = request.getQueryString(); //action=initASDF&requestId=9078-32&redirect=http://www.mydomain.com?actionId=4343
    System.out.println(getParamValue(qs, "requestId"));
```

The output should be, 9078-32

Comment: Why can't you use `request.getParameter("requestId")`, since you obviously have an `HttpServletRequest`? Reimplementing a query parser using a regex doesn't seem like the most productive thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a regex negated group. See this other SO question: [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)

You'll need to get everything except a `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to do it: `request.getParameter("requestId")`

Answer (score 0):

Could you split the string based on ampersands (&) and then search the resulting array for the key (look upto the equals sign).

Here's a link to String.split(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Here's the type of thing I'm talking about:

```
private static final String KEY_VALUE_SEPARATOR = "=";
private static final String QUERY_STRING_SEPARATOR = "&";

public String getParamValue(String entireQueryString, String paramName) {
    String[] fragments = entireQueryString.split(QUERY_STRING_SEPARATOR);
    for (String fragment : fragments){
        if (fragment.substring(0, fragment.indexOf(KEY_VALUE_SEPARATOR)).equalsIgnoreCase(paramName)){
            return fragment.substring(fragment.indexOf(KEY_VALUE_SEPARATOR)+1);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("can't find value");
}
```

The Exception at the end is a pretty rubbish idea but that's not really the important part of this.

Comment: Yes I can, But i don't think this as good solution in performance wise.