# Match anything that is a something?

Tags: regex

With regex how can a match everything in a string that isnt something? This may not make sense but read on.

So take the word `baby` for instance to match everything that *isn't* a `b` you would do something like `[^b]` and this would match `a` and `y`. Simple enough! But how in this string `Ben sits on a bench` can I match everything that isn't `ben` so i would be attempting to match `sits on a ch`?

Better yet match everything that isn't a pattern? e.g. in `1a2be3`  match everything that isn't `number,letter,number`, so it would match every combination in the string except `1a2`?

Comment: It sounds like you can just do a regex replace of your blacklisted pattern with the empty string and see if anything remains?

Comment: Can you give answer with an example?

Comment: @Srb1313711 Any programming language of choice? I'm not sure whether replacing can be done in a regex alone.

Comment: I don't think there is much to add to what I already wrote... you would replace e.g. `\d[a-z]\d` (number-letter-number) with the empty string and then check if the result is non-empty. If it isn't then you have a "match". Alternatively you could *split* on that regex, so the input `xxx1a2yyy` would result in two tokens `xxx` and `yyy`.

Comment: @skiwi no language of choice I am aware some features of regex are more or less in some languages than in others but for the sake of the question no, any language solution.

Comment: Could this be a dupe of [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/977251/758831)?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this? Are you looking to get the ranges, or the string, or to embed in a larger regexp, or what?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:ben)|(.)
```

What this regex does is match `ben` or any other character, however, `ben` isn't captured but the other characters are. So you'll end up with a lot of matches except for the `ben`'s. Then you can join all those matches together to get the string without the `ben`'s.

Here an example in python.

```
import re

thestr = "Ben sits on a bench"
regex = r'(?:ben)|(.)'

matches = re.findall(regex, thestr, re.IGNORECASE)
print ''.join(matches)
```

This will ouput:

```
 sits on a ch
```

Note the leading space. You can of course get rid of that by adding `.strip()`.

Also note, that it is probably faster to do a regex that replaces `ben` with an empty string to get the same result. But if you want to use this technique in a more complex regex it could come in handy.

And of course you can also put more complex regexes at the place of `ben`, so for example your `number,letter,number` example would be:

```
(?:[0-9][a-z][0-9])|(.)
```

Comment: Can you put a `*` to match everything else instead of matching *char by char* and using `.join` ?

Comment: If you would use `.*` it could match any `ben`'s, so no you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  You can't do what you're asking.  Technically, the first part has an ugly answer, but the second part (as I understand it) has no answer.

---

For your first part, I have a pretty impractical (yet pure regex) answer; anything better would require code (like @rednaw's much cleaner answer above).  I added to the test to make it more comprehensive.   (For simplicity, I'm using `grep -Pio` for PCRE, case insensitive, printing one match per line.)

```bsh
$ echo "Ben sits on a bench better end" \
    |grep -Pio '(?=b(?!en)|(?<!b)en|e(?!n)|(?<!be)n|[^ben])\w+'
sits
on
a
ch
better
end
```

I'm basically making a special case for any letter in "ben" so I can include only iterations that are not themselves part of the string "ben."  As I said, not really practical, even if I am technically answering your question.  I've also saved [a blow-by-blow explanation of this regex](http://regex101.com/r/aK0gT5) if you want further detail.

If you're forced into using a pure regex rather than code, your best bet for items like this is to write code to *generate* the regex.  That way you can keep a clean copy of it.

---

I'm not sure what you're asking for the remainder of your challenge; a regex is either greedy or lazy [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) [[2]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and I don't know of any implementations that can find "every combination" rather than merely the first combination by either method.  If there were such a thing, it would be very very slow in real life (rather than quick examples); the slow speed of regex engines would be intolerable if they were forced to examine every possibility, which would basically be a [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

Examples:

```
# greedy evaluation (default)
$ echo 1a2be3 |grep -Pio '(?!\d[a-z]\d)\w+'
a2be3

# lazy evaluation
$ echo 1a2be3 |grep -Pio '(?!\d[a-z]\d)\w+?'
a
2
b
e
3
```

I assume you are looking for `1` `1a` `a` `a2` `a2b` `a2be` `a2be3` `2` `2b` `2be` `2be3` `b` `be` `be3` `e` `e3` `3` but I don't think you can get that with a pure regex.  You'd need some code to generate every substring and then you could use a regex to filter out the forbidden pattern (again, this is all about greedy vs lazy vs ReDoS).

Comment: +1 Thank you for an very detailed response this cleary took time to write and althoug couldnt answer the question was still very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all the words except one, you can use negative lookahead: `\b(?!ben\b)\w*\b`, but for an answer to your exact question Jon's comment seems the simplest.

Comment: This didnt work for me I tested here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with my ben example and it only matched the first ben? Also can you explain the \b?

Comment: \b is word boundary, try here: http://regexpal.com/ works fine for me (although not exactly what you requested, since it matches words).

Answer (score 0):

Okay The simplest thing To Do is Match Everything

```
(.*?)
```

Then on the pattern matched do another Match for What you don't want(for e.g In perl you will have the pattern matched in the variable $&).

If it matches, That's not what you want else you have your match.

Simple A-B where A is everything(.*?) and B is What you don't want.So you end up doing two matches but i think that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace everything that *matches* your pattern with a blank (to delete it).

You haven't indicated what language you are using, so genetically:

```
s/ben//g
```

and your other example:

```
s/\d[a-zA-Z]\d//g
```

Comment: Im looking to match not replace, this may work but not what im looking for, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of strings, use "split on regexp" instead of "match on regexp".