# Regex to negate the whole word?

Tags: java, regex

```
  String test1 = "This is my test string";
```

I want to match a string which does not contain "test"

I can do it with

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?^(test).*?")
```

and it works but at most of sites like [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)
    `^(?!.*test).*$`  is suggested which did not work for me.

As per my understanding `^(test)` is sufficient so why  `^(?!.*test).*$` is required?

Comment: What do you think `^` means here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `if (!yourString.contains("test"))`

Comment: BTW There is 249 words containing `test` e.g. brightest contest detesting incontestabilities

Answer (score 29):

You want the following instead.

```
^(?:(?!test).)*$
```

Regular expression:

```
^               the beginning of the string
(?:             group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
 (?!            look ahead to see if there is not:
  test          'test'
 )              end of look-ahead
 .              any character except \n
)*              end of grouping
$               before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

With using `^(test)`, it is only looking for *test* at the beginning of the string, not negating it.

The negation `^` operator will only work inside of a character class `[^ ]`, but whole words do not work inside of a character class. For example `[^test]` matches any character except: (`t`, `e`, `s`, `t`)

Comment: why not just ^(test) ?

Comment: @user3198603 The `^` operator for negation only works in a character class, for example `[^t]` would accept any character that is not the letter t. But that does not work for whole words. That is, `[^test]` would accept any *letter* that is not t, e, or s. Outside of a character class, `^` is an anchor for beginning of line.

Comment: `\v^(%(test)@!.)*$` for regex in vim

Answer (score -2):

`.*` = anything zero or more times

The Regex:

```
^((?!test).)*$
```

I misunderstand it. Now I think it will work.

Comment: This accepts anything that *contains* test, which is not asked.

Comment: in fairness with the addendum "and then flip the result", this would be a perfectly good answer - probably an indicator that the OP shouldn't be using regex.