# negate the whole regex pattern when negative lookaround doesn't work

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I had a regex that matches a P.O. BOX on a given address - `/p\.? *o\.? *box/i`. But recently my requirement changes to **NOT** match the P.O. BOX. In other words, the address is valid when P.O. BOX is not found. I was trying to negate that pattern so it matches an address that has no P.O. BOX by using `negative lookahead`, this is what I came up with so far: `/.*(?!p\.? *o\.? *box).*/i`, but it is not working right now: https://regex101.com/r/oN1jZ8/1

For example, I try to match the following:

- this is a valid address

But not the following:

- this is a invalid address because it contains a **P.O. BOX**
- **po box** shows up so it is invalid

I am aware of a few similar posts, such as:

- [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)
- [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)
- [Regex to negate the whole word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724661/regex-to-negate-the-whole-word)

where pretty much the `negative lookaround` is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*p\.? *o\.? *box).*
```

Difference is use of start anchor `^` and use of `.*` inside the lookahead pattern.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN1jZ8/2)