# Regex - sets subtraction

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, swiftlint

I have to find all strings starting with //MARK that do not contain sting ABCDS. 
I had some trials but all failed. Biggest question here is to mark set A-B.

```
(\/\/[ ]*MARK[ \t]*[:]*[ \t]*[^\n(?P=ABCD)]*)
```

It should work with:

```
//MARK: MarABdasdsd
//MARK sthIsHere
```

But should not match:

```
//MARK: great marABCDE
```

I am able to find all cases but do not know how to remove this one. I can use only single regular expression.
I am aware of many posts [negate the whole regex pattern when negative lookaround doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438324/negate-the-whole-regex-pattern-when-negative-lookaround-doesnt-work)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? If it is a regular regex engine, use `\/\/[ ]*MARK[ \t]*:*[ \t]*(?:(?!ABCD)[^\n])*$`. Is it for iOS? :)

Comment: It is used to rise warnings on specific marks using SwiftLiint. I will check the answers and write if they work:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are coding in Swift that uses ICU regex flavor. It supports lookaheads, thus, the regex based on a tempered greedy token will work:

```
//[ ]*MARK[ \t]*:*[ \t]*(?:(?!ABCD)[^\n])*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC2bH7/1)

The regex matches

- `//` - two `/`
- `[ ]*` - 0+ spaces
- `MARK` - a literal word `MARK`
- `[ \t]*:*[ \t]*` - 0+ spaces or tabs followed with 0+ colons followed with 0+ tabs or spaces
- `(?:(?!ABCD)[^\n])*` - the tempered greedy token matching any non-newline symbol that does not start a `ABCD` sequence
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works :) Thanks a lot!