# Can anybody explain why result of [.^;] and [;] same in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions. While exploring it I found that result of the regular expression [.^;] and [;] are same and am trying to figure out an explanation.
String is Hello;World
As per my knowledge, ^ is for negation so shouldn't it skip the next character to it which is ';' in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[.^;]` doesn't do what you expect as `^` is treated as literal `^` only not negation.

To negate it use `^` at 1st position inside character class:

```
[^.;]
```

- `[.^;]` becomes a character class that matches literals `.` OR `^` OR `;`
- `[^.;]` becomes a negation character class that matches **anything but** literals `.` OR `;`
- `[;]` is also a character class that matches literal `;` only

Comment: appreciate the explanation @anubhava.. also I found this question helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group

Answer (score 1):

`^` only negates character groups if it is the first character in a group.

`[.^;]` will match *any* of the three characters in the group (a literal period, a caret or a semicolon). On the other hand, `[^.;]` will match anything *not* in the group (any letter, any digit, anything else but a literal period or semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

A carat `^` only means negation when it's the *first* character in a character class.

This regex `[.^;]` means "either a literal dot or a carat or a semi-colon"

This regex `[;]` means "a semi-colon".