# Adding characters end of URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have to migrate a shop site to another shop system.

The problem I have is that in new shop system, all products name must ended with `-detail` in the URL.

In today site here is the URL of a product:

```
domaine.com/shop/category1/productname
```

In new shop same product will have this URL:

```
domaine.com/shop/category1/productname-detail
```

I would like that when using this old URL `domaine.com/shop/category1/productname`, user will be redirected to right one: `domaine.com/shop/category1/productname-detail`

can this be done through htaccess without having to define a line for each product (~2500) ?

This shop has also normal URL like `domaine.com/contact` and I don't want to add `-detail` for those URL. Only when calling a product into a shop category.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with a [negating regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group) that matches anything that doesn't have `-detail` in the end. Have you tried to do anything yet, or are you expecting us to do your work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes I have tried to find a solution by searching into this forum but I couldn't find any solution suiting to my need. I will try to check what negating regex is.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using mod_rewrite. Make sure mod_rewrite module is loaded in your main config file. Then put the in your .htaccess. The condition makes sure the url does not end with -detail. Then an url with shop, followed by 2 other path parts is redirected to the same url with -detail appended.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-detail$
RewriteRule ^shop/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}-detail [R,L]
```

After testing this rule and making sure it works correctly, replace the `R` flag with `R=301` to make the redirect permanent.

Comment: @JeanCharle Please note that as the person that asked the question, you can mark answers as the accepted answer. See [this help-page for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).