# Qt Syntax Highlighter Example highlighting rule for single line comments

Tags: c++, regex, qt, syntax-highlighting, qt5.3

Taken from Qt Syntax Highlighter Example:

```
//single line comment rule
singleLineCommentFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGray);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("//[^\n]*");
rule.format = singleLineCommentFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);
//string rule
quotationFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\".*\"");
rule.pattern.setMinimal(true);
rule.format = quotationFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);
```

The Problem is when you have something like this:

```
"inside is darkGreen//"outside is darkGray
```

As you can see, the result is: inside the quotations will be gray including the double / . But the characters outside "" becomes darkGray which is supposed to be in default font color(normally, black). How do i adjust the RegExp for single line comment inorder for it to know that a green "//" is exempted from the darkGray highlighting rule?

I tried to add this for the singe line comment rule:

```
rule.pattern.setMinimal(true);
```

Still won't work. I Also tried:

```
rule.pattern = QRegExp("//[^\n]*\"*");
```

Comment: I also tried
        rule.pattern = QRegExp("//([^\n]*)| (?!\")");

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\"(?:(?!\/\/).)+?\")/
```

Using the magic of non-capturing groups and negative look aheads, I have engineered the following:

```
quotationFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\"(?:(?!\\/\\/).)+\"");//QRegExp("\".*\"");

rule.pattern.setMinimal(true);
rule.format = quotationFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);
```

Magic applied, and you get the behavior you are looking for.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/999943

http://regexr.com/3an21

and also tested in this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough?: `(\"[^/"]+\")`

Comment: But then you can't put a single forward slash inside double quotes.  Also, I don't think non-capturing groups is a requirement, but I didn't study to see if capture groups were leveraged elsewhere in the code.

Comment: This is the output: "all are black before //"the rest are gray