# not-group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I understand that `[^A-Za-z]` would match any character that's not a letter.

Is there any way to do this with a group? For example: `(?^:&amp;)` - would match any sequence of characters that is not the sequence `&amp;`

**NOTE:** as [Mark Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797049/mark-reed) pointed out, it would be pointless to match an empty string, as an empty string is a sequence of characters that is not the sequence, so I would like the regex to match *as many characters as possible*

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

in `Ben &amp; Jerry's` the matches would be `Ben`  and  `Jerry's` (note that the whitespaces after `Ben` and before `Jerry's` are captured too.

**NOTE:** if possible,  please do not use *look behinds*, because I will be using the regex in a JS script, and Javascript does not support look behinds.

Comment: @anubhava fixed it. sorry, I got *behinds* and *aheads* mixed up

Comment: It will be much easier to split the input by `&amp;`

Comment: unfortunately, while splitting may seem simple, in my script it will make it more complicated. My script's objective is to bullet-proof regexes where the string-to-be-matched will not contain any `&`, but only `&amp;`s, It's a bit complicated after that point, but a split will not work sadly.

Comment: @anubhava I need a solution that fixes the regex, and not the script

Comment: Just a side node: `[^A-z]` will **not** exactly do what you're trying to achieve. Have a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and you'll see that other characters won't be matched either. Be more precise with `[^A-Za-z]` if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Jan good point. will fix.

Comment: Negation is tricky for general regular expressions.  After all, the empty string is "a sequence of characters that is not `&amp;`".  I think what you want is "a sequence of as many characters as possible that does not include `&amp;`".

Comment: @MarkReed thought that was a bit obvious, but I will include that detail in the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a regex that will match alternatives, and will only *capture* into Group 1 the last alternative that will present a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (or an unrolled version for better performance - if you only have 2 or 3):

```
&amp;|((?:(?!&amp;)[\s\S])+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO3uW7/1) (an [unrolled version - `&amp;|([^&]*(?:&(?!amp;)[^&]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lO3uW7/2)

The pattern:

- `&amp;` - matches `&` entity
- `|` - or
- `((?:(?!&amp;)[\s\S])+)` - matches and captures into group 1 any chunk of text (1+ characters) that is not a starting point for a `&amp;` sequence. Since it is for JS, you need a `[\s\S]` (or `[^]`) to match any character *including* a newline. Otherwise, use `.` instead (if you only intend to match *lines*).

```js
var re = /&amp;|((?:(?!&amp;)[\s\S])+)/g; 
var str = 'abc Ben &amp; Jerry\'s    foobar ssss  sss  sss &amp;\n\n\nsssss&amp;sssss     &amp;\n\nsssss&amp;sssss     &amp;sssss\n&amp;sssss&amp;\n&amp;&amp;';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {// A part of code only necessary for the 
        re.lastIndex++;            // unrolled pattern (as it can match empty string)
    }
    res.push(m[1]);                // Only collect the captured texts
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>BEFORE:<br/>" + str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') + "</pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>AFTER:<br/>" + res.join("") + "</pre>";
```

Comment: really good solution. I approve. Only one issue, which won't matter in *my script*, but may matter in someone else's: It will match the `&amp;` so that using re.test(str) will result to true if the string is "&amp;" only.

Comment: It will get matched but not *captured*, so one will still be able to tell a `&` from non-`&`.

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
(.*?)(?:&amp;)|((?!&amp;).*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0gF7/2)

### Explanation:

1. `(.*?)`: Take everything but non greedy.
2. `(?:&amp;)`: `?:` is non-capturing group. A group that you don't want to get the value.
3. `((?!&amp;).*)$`: get the rest of the string which is not `&amp;`

Comment: if there are no characters, just whitespaces, the whitespaces won't match... pretty damn good sulution though.

Comment: Thanks. Why would you need the whitespace anyway. If you like the answer, can you please accept it?

Comment: and... `Ben&amp;Jerry's` would not match correctly. And I can't accept it yet. The solution will not work good enough for my script. I need it a bit more bullet proof.

Comment: And it won't match `foobar` in `Ben &amp; Jerry's foobar`

Comment: I perfected your regex nearly almost. `((?:^|\s)(?:(?:(?!&amp;)\S+)(?:\s|$)*)*)` works if and only if there are white spaces surrounding the `&amp` might want to update your answer to that. example: https://regex101.com/r/tT1nZ7/1

Comment: Improved my answer! Yeay! I am so proud at myself. There is a much simpler solution. Please accept

Comment: hmm... pretty simplicit, however, the `&amp;` will still be matched, but that will not be a problem in *my script*, but it may be a problem in someone else's, and that only works if there is only one instance of `&amp;` for example `&amp;&amp;` will not match properly. https://regex101.com/r/qQ0gF7/1

Comment: This time, it's perfect, I promise. Can you please review? Hehe, thx

Comment: Why does it need the second `&amp;`? As far as I can see it will try to match the first alternative and only if it cannot will it try the other, in which case "&amp;" will not be present. Also, `((?!&amp;).*)` will match the "amp;" part of "&amp;", since the negative lookahead is only satisfied when facing the entire string. Note that the last Kleene star makes the expression match empty on every line. I'm using `(.*?)(?:&amp;)|(.+)$` as a result.

Comment: @Scratte to cover the possibility of the existence of another unexpected `&amp;`