# How to match a text with a token an expression with/without negative lookahead in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Supposed to have a comma separated string of text, where each text has or not - comma separated -  a token in a list like

```
var tokens=['Inc.','Ltd','LLC'];
```

so the string is like

```
var companies="Apple, Inc., Microsoft, Inc., Buzzfeed, Treasure, LLC";
```

I want to obtain this array as output

```
var companiesList = [
    "Apple Inc.",
    "Microsoft Inc.",
    "Buzzfeed",
    "Treasure LLC"
    ];
```

So I firstly did a `RegExp` like that

```
var regex=new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+("+token+")", "gi" )
```

that I get the matches and search for a regex like

```
var regex=new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+("+item+")", "i" )
```

for each of the tokens:

```
tokens.forEach((item) => {
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+(" + item + ")", "gi")
    var matches = companies.match(regex) || []
    console.log(item, regex.toString(), matches)
    matches.forEach((m) => {
        var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+(" + item + ")", "i")
        var match = m.match(regex)
        if (match && match.length > 2) {
            var n = match[1].trim();
            var c = match[2].trim();
            companiesList.push(n + ' ' + c);
        }
    });
});
```

In this way I can capture the tokens and concat matching groups 1 and 2.

```js
var tokens = ['inc.', 'ltd', 'llc'],
  companies = "Apple, Inc., Microsoft, Inc., Buzzfeed, Treasure, LLC",
  companiesList = [];
tokens.forEach((item) => {
  var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+(" + item + ")", "gi")
  var matches = companies.match(regex) || []
  console.log( item, regex.toString(), matches )
  matches.forEach((m) => {
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z&/? ]*),\\s+(" + item + ")", "i")
    var match = m.match(regex)
    if (match && match.length > 2) {
      var n = match[1].trim();
      var c = match[2].trim();
      companiesList.push(n + ' ' + c);
    }
  });
});

console.log(companiesList)
```

The problem is that I'm missing the comma separated text without a token after the comma like: `Buzzfeed`.

The idea is to use a non capturing group in a negative look ahead ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group) about non capturing groups in regex match)

```
/([a-zA-Z]*)^(?:(?!ltd).)+$/gi
```

But in this way I have any match when in the input string the token is present:

```
"Apple, Inc., Microsoft, Inc., Buzzfeed, Treasure LLC".match( /([a-zA-Z]*)^(?:(?!llc).)+$/gi )
```

while I want to match only the text that do not have it so I would like to get - like the opposite before:

```
["Buzzfeed"]
```

So how to negate/modify the previous code to work in both cases to obtain at the end the composed array:

```
var companiesList = [
        "Apple Inc.",
        "Microsoft Inc.",
        "Buzzfeed",
        "Treasure LLC"
        ];
```

Comment: You misunderstand the answer in the popular SO question about matching  a string not containing a word. You need `(?!ltd|etc)` lookahead where you may add alternatives after a pipe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew uhm it's possible, but check the code, and try with that I have some patterns to respect like `Name, Inc.`. So I have to match this pattern and the latter (without).

Comment: To just match Buzzfeed, you need to exclude matching those `LLC`, etc. and also all words that are followed with them. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/wav6gaob/) does not look nice. Maybe adaneo is suggesting a better way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just reduce it, and just check the token list as you go

```js
var tokens    = ['Inc.','Ltd','LLC'];
var companies = "Apple, Inc., Microsoft, Inc., Buzzfeed, Treasure, LLC";

var result    = companies.split(',').reduce( (a,b,i) => {
    return tokens.indexOf(b.trim()) === -1  ? a.push(b.trim()) : a[a.length-1] += b,a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hahaha too much `RegExp` overhead in my mind. I assume that your solution it should work pretty good in most of cases! +1. will try it in my scenary but it seems extremely clever.

Comment: It's really just a suggestion, but it seemed a lot easier than that regex nightmare, and yes, it should work with anything, as long as the value is in the tokenlist, and would be easy to make it case-insensitive, trim of whitespace, or anything else you'd need.

Comment: Absolutely thanks, since there are odd cases like "Inc." and "inc", etc, at some point maybe it is better to have all in, and the regex nightmare is true!

Comment: Also, [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/w6nxuzmq/) a little less golfed, probably easier to work with.

Comment: thanks. It seems it only fails when there is a trailing `","` like `"Apple Inc., Facebook, "`, so it will push a `""` in the array, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/02me7cm0/)

Comment: Sure, if you change the string to a different format, where you have commas other places as well, it won't work as expected. In this case it should be easy to filter out the empty string though -> https://jsfiddle.net/02me7cm0/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex for splitting.

```js
var companies = "Apple, Inc., Microsoft, Inc., Buzzfeed, Treasure, LLC";

console.log(companies.split(/,\s(?!Inc\.|Ltd|LLC)/i).map(s => s.replace(', ', ' ')));
```

Comment: This also works, but how to apply to an array of tokens of arbitrary length?