# how to remove html tags like span but prefixed by html entities

Tags: c#, regex

I find the HtmlEditorExtender in the Ajax Toolkit (which extends a textbox to enable a user to input text which is saved as html), if you paste text from Word into it produces things this when you post back.

`&lt;span style="line-height: 115%; font-size: 18pt;"&gt;`

I have a regular expression which gets rid of unwanted tags like `<span style="font-size:16px;">` and `</span>`. I need a regular expression that will get rid of `&lt;` and `&gt;` and anything between them.

I tried modifying the expression I have that gets rid of unwanted tags when they have a `<` or a `/>` at the beginning or end which is ..

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"<[/]?(font|span|xml|del|ins|[ovwxp]:\w+)[^>]*?>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and came up with

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(&lt;)[/]?(font|span|xml|del|ins|[ovwxp]:\w+)[^(&gt;)]*?>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but it is doing nothing. How can I get rid of tags like span (and anything like styles in the tag) which have been html encoded into their respective entities?

Comment: Can you decode it first (to turn the &gt; back to >)  ?  Then your original regex would work.

Comment: As Eric Burdo commented, use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx), or [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) if it's running on a web server, to reduce the problem to one you have already solved.

Comment: [^(&gt;)] doesn't work because [^abc] checks for characters including '(' and ')'

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group