# Regex - Not match end of line for IOC IP|PORT

Tags: php, regex, port, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to create a regex expression that match something that is not formatted as : ip|port.
A port value can be between [1, 65535].

**Examples of set of data:**
(1) 8.8.8.8|0     (bad: port 0 not allowed)
(2) 8.8.8.8|1     (good)
(3) 8.8.8.8|65536 (bad: port > 65535)
(4) 8.8.8.8|dawda (bad: char)

The regex expression (match bad data) should match (1), (3) and (4).

***Consider that the ip part will always be right*** (no need to regex it) and what I need to check is the port. Because of that, I started the evaluation by the end of the line like this:

**Regex to match a port between 0 and 65535:**
\|(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})

**[Regex with end of line matching:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dx7r.jpg)**
\|(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})$

Now, I want to negate it to catch line that dosent end with a valid port. I look in other forums ([How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex), [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)) and learn about negative lookahead regex.

According to those forums and negative lookahead regex, my regex should be as:

^(?!(MY_REGEX)).*$

I modified my regex and added .* for the ip part to plug the ^.

[Negative regex at end of line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fcCK.jpg):
^(?!.*\|(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})).*$

The problem I have is the ending part .*$ which allow something after the port number. In the end, this code will be executed with **PHP**. According to PHP, variable length look-behind is not supported, which make me choose lookahead regex in first place.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend using a simple regex for basic syntax validation, and use a capturing group on the number after the the `|`. Then in your code use a method to validate the number's range. Regex doesn't do math very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way is by capturing the part after `|` with `(.*)` (any 0+ chars other than line break chars) and validating it with a bit of PHP code:

```
if (preg_match('~^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\|(.*)$~', $s, $res)) {
    if (ctype_digit($res[1]) && intval($res[1]) > 0 && intval($res[1]) < 65536 ) { // valid port, omit
        echo "The port is valid: " . $res[1];
    } else {
        echo "Invalid port: " . $res[1];
    }
}
```

The [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) checks if the string only contains digits.

See the [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/sV2pcC).

If you just need a pattern that will be PCRE compatible, you may use the following pattern:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\|(?!(?:[1-9]\d{0,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$)(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PT8j7X/1)

See the details below:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+){3}` - 3 sequences of a `.` followed with 1+ digits (an IP pattern that needs no validation, you consider it pre-validated)
- `\|` - a literal `|`
- `(?!(?:[1-9]\d{0,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if it finds the following numeric values at the end of the string:

  - `[1-9]\d{0,3}` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then 0 to 3 digits (`1` to `9999`)
  - `[1-5]\d{4}` - a digit from `1` to `5` and then 4 digits (`10000` to `59999`)
  - `6[0-4]\d{3}` - `6`, a digit from `0` to `4` and then 3 digits (`60000` to `64999`)
  - `65[0-4]\d{2}` - `65`, a digit from `0` to `4`, and 2 digits (`65000` to `65499`)
  - `655[0-2]\d` - `655`, a digit from `0` to `2`, and 1 digit (`65500` to `65529`)
  - `6553[0-5]` - `65530` to `65535`.
- `(.*)` - capture the part that is not a valid port, any 0+ chars (other than line break chars) up to the end of string
- `$` - end of string.