# How do I replace everything except for the parameter String (Word)

Tags: java, replaceall

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word){

String bob = str.replaceAll(^word,"+");

return bob;

}
```

Sample Input and Output:

I want to replace everything in String(str) that's not String(word) with a +

```
plusOut("1234xy5678", "xy")     == "++++xy++++"
plusOut("ghlnds4pl4qwqd4", "4") == "++++++4++4++++4"
```

^word<---how would I make the method replace everything except for word

I want to replace my String(str) with a "+" except the String(word). How would I go about doing this using replaceAll method.

Comment: Do you **have** to use `replaceAll`? Because if `word` is more than one character long, I don't think you can use it. Also, can `word` occur more than once in `str`? If so, do you want every occurrence of `word` to be preserved, or just the first (or last) one?

Comment: I would think that using replaceAll would be the easiest method for the problem since it is able to take a string and replace everything. The only thing is I want everything that is not the imputed String(word)

Comment: Well you could also loop using indexOf

Comment: I could, but it would be easier just to do it in a couple of lines

Comment: does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group

Answer (score 0):

Your `replaceAll` method is almost there.

You need to change it to something like:

```
String bob = str.replaceAll("[^" + word + "]", "+");
```

You can see the two outputs requested [here](https://ideone.com/yUSbNq) and [here](https://ideone.com/e5MyKf)