# Don't match if character plus space is present before a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex matches "so" when it's preceded by a comma and a space:

```
(,\s)(so)
```

I want to do the opposite now. I want to tell the regex: don't match "so" if it's preceded by a comma and a space. I tried this (after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group) SO question):

```
^(,\s)(so)
```

But now the regex doesn't match anything: https://regexr.com/4kgq8.

Note: I'm not trying to match beginning of the line.

Comment: You may use negative lookahead `/(?<!, )so/g` but it is only supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to tell the regex: don't match "so" if it's preceded by a comma and a space.

Best solution is to use a negative lookbehind as I mentioned in my comment below question:

```
/(?<!, )so/g
```

Here, `(?<!, )` is a negative lookbehind expression that fails the match if a comma and space is present before `so`.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/0YCBmG/1)

Caveat is that `lookbehind` support in Javascript is only available in modern browsers.

---

If you want to support legacy or older browsers also then approach will be to use a captured group and discard unwanted match in alternation:

```
/(?:, so|(\bso))\b/g
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0YCBmG/2)

Here a match is defined by presence of capture group #1 in each match. We are matching and discarding unwanted match of `", so` in left hand side of alternation. Our desired matches string is on right hand side of alternation which is captured in group #1.

**Code:**

```js
var arr = ['So that', 
'so big that', 
', so so'];

const regex = /(?:, so|(\bso))\b/g;

arr.forEach((el) => {
  m = regex.exec(el);
  if (m && m.length > 1)
    console.log('Line; [', el, ' ] Start:', regex.lastIndex, m[1])
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Atom's regex search feature, so I can't choose groups.

Comment: If lookbehind is supported in Atom's regex engine then that will be best solution.

Comment: Oh, I updated Aom and the negative look behind seems to work now. Thanks.

Comment: Great, negative lookbehind is best possible solution for this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use alternation, if that'd be OK, with an expression without lookarounds such as:

```
, so|(\bso\b)
```

```js
const regex = /, so|(\bso\b)/gmi;
const str = `So that 
so big that 
, so
and not , so
, so so`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pKqaKO/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/pKqaKO/1debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: OP is not trying to match start-of-line, they were (incorrectly) guessing at a negation operator (by analogy from character class negation).

Comment: This is not correct as it will fail to match 2nd `so` in `, so so`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using Atom's regex search ... not a JavaScript program.

Comment: ...Then why tag with [tag:javascript] and not [tag:atom-editor]?!?

Answer (score 1):

As anubhava mentions in the comment, with negative *lookbehind* you could do `/(?<!,\s)(so)/`, which would match `so` that is *not* preceded by a comma and a space (and capturing `so`). This is a reverse from `/(?<=,\s)(so)/`, which matches `so` that *is* preceded by a comma and a space.

Your regexp `/(,\s)(so)/` matches a comma, a space and `so` (and captures the comma and the space in one group, and `so` in another). The negation of that can be constructed using a negative *lookahead*, supported in all browsers, like so: `/((?!,\s)..|^.?)(so)/` — it will match two characters (or less, if at the start of the string) that are not a comma and a space, then `so` (and capture both the non-comma-space preceding characters, and `so`).

Typically, this second approach has a drawback: when you match more than you want, the restriction against overlapping matches might make you lose a match here and there. However, in this particular case, it is not a problem, since any overlapping characters would be `so`, not a comma and a space.

(EDIT: I wrote "space" here but all the expressions are written following OP's use of `\s`, which is actually for *whitespace*, which includes more than just space.)