# Match all HTML tags except for <li> with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check some string containing HTML to see if it will contain any `<li>` elements, and filter out every element except for the `<li>` elements.

For example,

```
<li>foo</li><p><em>bar</em><em style="color: rgb(161, 0, 0);">fiddle</em></p><p><em class="ql-font-couriernew" style="color: rgb(61, 20, 102);">dog</em></p>
```

Would become

```
<li>foo</li>barfiddledog
```

I can figure out how to capture just `<li>` elements, or all HTML elements, but I can't figure out how to capture only elements that are not `<li>`.

I am using `(<\/?[^(li)]>)+`, but this seems to only filter out the `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `<\/?(?:(?!li).)+>` should do the trick. I've taken notes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/9484862 to edit your existing regex code, which was already nearly working.

Comment: Awesome! I had taken a look at that before posting, but couldn't quite get it working. Regex is a mystery half the time.

What you have worked most of the way, but it was filtering out the closing `</li>` tag too. Not too big of a deal, but I was also able to extend it to not filter out the closing `</li>` tag as well with `(<(?:(?!\/?li)).+?>)`
https://regex101.com/r/Sm4Azv/2

And thank you so much for actually answering instead of masturbating about dom objects for pixel points