# Regex XML Selection Extract Element

Tags: python, regex

I am trying make a regex selection starting from `BYPASS 0 0 0` up to and including the section where it says `WAK 0 0`  Here is what I have `(?s)(?=BYPASS).*?(WAK....)` I think my syntax for python use is incorrect also here is how I use it in python script `re.split(r'(?s)(?=BYPASS).*?(WAK....)', r)`  I believe this is causing the problem for me `(?s)` resulting with incorrect regex selections.

```
<REAPER_PROJECT 0.1 "6.66/win64" 1661879469
  <NOTES 0 2
  >
  RIPPLE 0
  GROUPOVERRIDE 0 0 0
  AUTOXFADE 129
  ENVATTACH 3
  POOLEDENVATTACH 0
  MIXERUIFLAGS 11 48
  PEAKGAIN 1
  FEEDBACK 0
  PANLAW 1
  PROJOFFS 0 0 0
  MAXPROJLEN 0 600
  GRID 3199 8 1 8 1 0 0 0
  TIMEMODE 1 5 -1 30 0 0 -1
  VIDEO_CONFIG 0 0 256
  PANMODE 3
  CURSOR 0
  ZOOM 100 0 0
  VZOOMEX 6 0
  USE_REC_CFG 0
  RECMODE 1
  SMPTESYNC 0 30 100 40 1000 300 0 0 1 0 0
  LOOP 0
  LOOPGRAN 0 4
  RECORD_PATH "" ""
  <RECORD_CFG
    ZXZhdxgAAA==
  >
  <APPLYFX_CFG
  >
  RENDER_FILE ""
  RENDER_PATTERN mask
  RENDER_FMT 0 2 44100
  RENDER_1X 0
  RENDER_RANGE 1 0 0 16 1000
  RENDER_RESAMPLE 3 0 1
  RENDER_ADDTOPROJ 0
  RENDER_STEMS 2048
  RENDER_DITHER 0
  TIMELOCKMODE 1
  TEMPOENVLOCKMODE 1
  ITEMMIX 1
  DEFPITCHMODE 589824 0
  TAKELANE 1
  SAMPLERATE 44100 0 0
  <RENDER_CFG
    ZXZhdyAAAA==
  >
  LOCK 1
  <METRONOME 6 2
    VOL 0.25 0.125
    FREQ 800 1600 1
    BEATLEN 4
    SAMPLES "" ""
    PATTERN 2863311530 2863311529
    MULT 1
  >
  GLOBAL_AUTO -1
  TEMPO 120 4 4
  PLAYRATE 1 0 0.25 4
  SELECTION 0 0
  SELECTION2 0 0
  MASTERAUTOMODE 0
  MASTERTRACKHEIGHT 0 0
  MASTERPEAKCOL 16576
  MASTERMUTESOLO 0
  MASTERTRACKVIEW 0 0.6667 0.5 0.5 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1 0
  MASTERHWOUT 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1
  MASTER_NCH 2 2
  MASTER_VOLUME 1 0 -1 -1 1
  MASTER_PANMODE 3
  MASTER_FX 1
  MASTER_SEL 0
  <MASTERPLAYSPEEDENV
    EGUID {07BFCFC9-6DA0-4D9C-8821-7D1555F3F3F8}
    ACT 0 -1
    VIS 0 1 1
    LANEHEIGHT 0 0
    ARM 0
    DEFSHAPE 0 -1 -1
  >
  <TEMPOENVEX
    EGUID {9059CD91-68BB-42A7-8E08-BCDDCB3AC50B}
    ACT 0 -1
    VIS 1 0 1
    LANEHEIGHT 0 0
    ARM 0
    DEFSHAPE 1 -1 -1
  >
  <PROJBAY
  >
  <TRACK {7233B3F7-03A2-4203-B516-704EFF3393E3}
    NAME dac
    PEAKCOL 16576
    BEAT -1
    AUTOMODE 0
    VOLPAN 1 0 -1 -1 1
    MUTESOLO 0 0 0
    IPHASE 0
    PLAYOFFS 0 1
    ISBUS 0 0
    BUSCOMP 0 0 0 0 0
    SHOWINMIX 1 0.6667 0.5 1 0.5 -1 -1 -1
    SEL 0
    REC 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
    VU 2
    TRACKHEIGHT 138 0 0 0 0 0
    INQ 0 0 0 0.5 100 0 0 100
    NCHAN 4
    FX 1
    TRACKID {7233B3F7-03A2-4203-B516-704EFF3393E3}
    PERF 0
    MIDIOUT -1
    MAINSEND 1 0
    <FXCHAIN
      WNDRECT 330 364 511 642
      SHOW 0
      LASTSEL 2
      DOCKED 0
      BYPASS 0 0 0
      <VST "VST: FreeG (Sonalksis)" "Sonalksis FreeG Stereo (64 bit).dll" 0 "" 1181894483<56535446724753667265656700000000> ""
        U0dyRu5e7f4CAAAAAQAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAABAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAEAAAAAABAA
        aH5iPgAAAD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AE5vbmUAEAAAAA==
      >
      PRESETNAME None
      FLOATPOS 0 0 0 0
      FXID {B7036F0D-9C41-461A-B1F6-CEB9D441E7EF}
      WAK 0 0
      BYPASS 0 0 0
      <VST "VST: FreeG (Sonalksis)" "Sonalksis FreeG Stereo (64 bit).dll" 0 "" 1181894483<56535446724753667265656700000000> ""
        U0dyRu5e7f4CAAAAAQAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAABAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAEAAAAAABAA
        uDDmPQAAAD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AE5vbmUAEAAAAA==
      >
      PRESETNAME None
      FLOATPOS 0 0 0 0
      FXID {9EEDFB75-3908-406D-BB87-69B4E868EDEA}
      WAK 0 0
      BYPASS 0 0 0
      <VST "VST: FreeG (Sonalksis)" "Sonalksis FreeG Stereo (64 bit).dll" 0 "" 1181894483<56535446724753667265656700000000> ""
        U0dyRu5e7f4CAAAAAQAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAABAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAEAAAAAABAA
        I8XFPgAAAD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AE5vbmUAEAAAAA==
      >
      PRESETNAME None
      FLOATPOS 0 0 0 0
      FXID {B0417D0E-CEA3-4E1F-9BF3-7D4DCE72AC39}
      WAK 0 0
    >
    <ITEM
      POSITION 0
      SNAPOFFS 0
      LENGTH 14.22222222222222
      LOOP 1
      ALLTAKES 0
      FADEIN 1 0.01 0 1 0 0 0
      FADEOUT 1 0.01 0 1 0 0 0
      MUTE 0 0
      SEL 1
      IGUID {D7A853A4-5113-4456-A452-7369A41CBB08}
      IID 1
      NAME dac.wav
      VOLPAN 1 0 1 -1
      SOFFS 0
      PLAYRATE 1 1 0 -1 0 0.0025
      CHANMODE 0
      GUID {723895C2-2164-4743-9EAD-77CD9086FD1A}
      <SOURCE WAVE
        FILE "dac.wav"
      >
    >
  >
>
```

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Comment: Can't seem to select last element of the xml files vst element, the regex selections are incorrect. Basically trying to parse the vst element section with extra data that follows it that has WAK and BYPASS parameters, the BYPASS actually where it starts up to WAK section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "regex selection".
The text you want can be matched with the regex `(?s)(BYPASS 0 0 0.*?WAK 0 0)` where:

```
"(?s)" signifies that the '.' char can match any character, including a newline
"("    begin capturing group
"BYPASS 0 0 0" the literal characters
".*?"  zero or more times any char, including newlines
"WAK 0 0" the literal characters
")"    end capturing group
```

You use `re.split(regex, txt)` that splits the string `txt` at the points specified by `regex` and returns an array of the new strings.

e.g.

```
x = re.split("a","bananas")
# x = ['b','n','n',s']

x = re.split("(a)", "bananas")
# x = ['b','a','n','a','n','a','s']
```

If what you want is to get the parts that start from `BYPASS 0 0 0` and end with `WAK 0 0`, you can use `re.findall(regex, txt)` that returns all the parts from `txt` that match `regex`.

e.g.

```
x = re.findall(r"b\w*s", "bananas, beers and bootstrap 5")
# x = ['bananas', 'beers', 'boots']
```

Or in your case

```
x = re.findall("(?s)(BYPASS 0 0 0.*?WAK 0 0)", txt)
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude one of the selections, eg. let's say we got 3 elements of the xml selected with this regular expression and one of them has a keyword eg. ```.wav``` I would like to use to isolate and exclude and make regular expression skip this element, do we use some kind of negative lookahead regex to achieve this xml element filtering by keyword ?

Comment: Well, since this is python you can just scan `all_matches` and remove anyone you don't like. Also, [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/13001874) shows a way to do it in pure regex! By incorporating Peter's regex, you can just replace `.*?` with `(?:(?!\.wav).)*?` and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/XqVTds/2) is an example of the following matching regex at work:

```
BYPASS.*?(?:WAK \d \d)
```

This is how you implement the regex in Python:

```py
import re
matches = re.findall(r'BYPASS.*?(?:WAK \d \d)', string, flags=re.S|re.M)
```

I had to get rid of the capture group with `?:` and set the flags as a parameter to get it to work, but this should be what you need.